# Understanding the definition of prime element.

Tags: abstract-algebra

I have trouble understanding the definition of a prime element. The definition says that
$p$ is a prime element if $p$ divides $ab$ 
then either $p$ divides $a$ or $p$ divides 
$b$.
but if we consider the integer 10, then it divides 
$2 \cdot 20$ and also divides 20,
so is 10 a prime elenent?
can you explain this?

Comment: The prime elements of the ring $\mathbb Z$ are the integers with an absolute value beging a prime number. $1$ is usually ruled out.

Comment: But it satisfies the definition of a prime element,
the definition says nothing about $p$ being
a prime number.

Comment: But it must satisfy the property for every elements $a,b$ in the ring.

Comment: If $R$ is a unital ring then $p\in R$ is a prime element in $R$ if $p$ is not a unit and satisfies: $\forall a,b\in R[p\mid ab\implies p\mid a\vee p\mid b]$.

Answer (score 2):

It must be true for **every** pair $a,b$ that satisfies $p\mid ab$.

Observe that also $10\mid4\times5$ while $10$ does not divide $4$ and does not divide $5$. This shows that $10$ is not prime.

Answer (score 2):

You're overlooking the quantifiers; the implication needs to hold for ***all*** $a$ and $b$, not merely for a single choice of $a$ and $b$.